# Force React component that have not mounted to DOM render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a class that's a component of React. How can I force that class render and return to me a DOM element?

For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{...}
const myVirtualDOMComponentButNotMountToAnywhere = <MyComponent {...someprops} />

// is there any function that
const myDOMElement = MyComponent.createDOMElement();
// or
const myDOMElement = myVirtualDOMComponentButNotMountToAnywhere.renderAsDOMElement();
// return a result that similar to
document.createElement(...);
```

I want to get that DOM element to perform custom mount (or what ever I want to) to that DOM element as the result from my function I expect that similar to the result of [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

For another example as a real usecase:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const myLink = <Link to='/...' />
const myDOMLink = myLink.renderAsDOMElement();
document.getElementById('someId').appendChild(myDOMLink);
```

Comment: You can use react refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Sounds like you want a react [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

Answer (score 0):

I may was too overthinking. It was provided as an API of `react-dom`: `render`

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('someId'))
```